# I am able to web scrape two reddit pages until a certain point, then I get an error and I don't understand why

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp

I am trying to conduct some NLP on subreddit pages. I have a chunk of code that gathers a bunch of data two web pages. It scrapes data until I get to range(40). This would be fine, except I know that the subreddits I have chosen have more posts than my code is allowing me to scrape.

Could anyone figure out what is going on here?

````
posts_test = []
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/TheOnion/.json?after='
for i in range(40):
    res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Maithili'})
    the_onion = res.json()
    for i in range(25):
        post_t = []
        post_t.append(the_onion['data']['children'][i]['data']['title'])
        post_t.append(the_onion['data']['children'][i]['data']['subreddit'])
        posts_test.append(post_t)
    after = the_onion['data']['after']
    url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/TheOnion/.json?after=' + after

    time.sleep(3)

# Not the onion
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/nottheonion/.json?after='

for i in range(40):
    res3 = requests.get(url, headers=headers2)
    not_onion_json = res2.json()
    for i in range(25):
        post_t = []
        post_t.append(not_onion_json['data']['children'][i]['data']['title'])
        post_t.append(not_onion_json['data']['children'][i]['data']['subreddit'])
        posts_test.append(post_t)
    after = not_onion_json['data']['after']
    url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/nottheonion/.json?after=" + after

    time.sleep(3)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-6c1cfdd42421> in <module>
      7     for i in range(25):
      8         post_t = []
----> 9         post_t.append(the_onion['data']['children'][i]['data']['title'])
     10         post_t.append(the_onion['data']['children'][i]['data']['subreddit'])
     11         posts_test.append(post_t)

IndexError: list index out of range"```
````

Comment: Why are you using a hard coded number?  Doesn't not_onion_json['data']['children'] have a length (or similar) property on it you can use instead?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are stopping at 40 is because you are telling python to stop at 40

```
for i in range(40):
```

The good news is you are collecting the next page here

```
after = not_onion_json['data']['after']
```

On the assumption that once you get to the end of the pages `after == null`, I would suggest performing a while loop. Something like

```
while after != None:
```

That will continue until you get to the end.